# Location updates At Server under specific Conditions

Tags: algorithm, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I have implemented CLLocationManager to monitor significant location changes. So I get updates at around 500 metres or more I update it to the server. But now I need to update the location only when the user stops moving. That means if a user moves a distance 10 km and stops moving. Then it should be updated to the server, not in between.

I was able to control the location update operation at every 500 metres by checking the speed from CLLocationManager, but however for cases like if the user travels a distance of around 700 meters and getting stable at that point. The location update fails as it fails to qualify 500-meter change.

Can anyone help me with an idea so as to how to check if the user is stable at a particular point?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To register smaller movement changes, I'd refer to [HealthKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit) instead of [CLLocationManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager).

For registering changes higher than that, what are you using in terms of accuracy?

You could try: `self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;`